# How to georeference an image with only eastings and northings

Tags: arcgis-desktop, georeferencing, mapping

How would I georeference the image below. All I have is the information provided on the Image below (showing easting and northings). I am focusing on Georeferencing the section In **red**. Once Georeferenced I was going to create a polygon shape around the area to act as the new shapefile. I am using ArcGIS V10.6.1

[image]

The only Lat and Long I have is for the center of the area

[image]

I need the area to be in the **black box** in the image below

[image]

Am I Georeferencing correctly as seen below?

[image]

Comment: You could draw the lines connection your border coordinates using any image manipulation software, then use the crosses to georeference, save the points and reference the original image.

Comment: @Erik has a solution, but it depends on line of latitude and longitude on the map being straight, which they might not be if its something like a conical projection. But it all looks pretty straight and square. Join the edges and see.

Comment: is this the only way or is there a way to do this without the image manipulation software?

Comment: Im not sure what you mean by join the edges? could you please provide a step by step guide

Comment: I just realized that the blue hashed area seems to be a Natura 2000 site. Get the official data on those and reference using the corners.

Comment: The hashed area for Nature 2000 only provides the information for SACs in British waters, Klaverbank is Dutch and I'm finding it difficult to get that information

Comment: In your final image you are not entering the correct values.  The grid on the map is in degrees and minutes so you need to convert those into decimal degrees.  There are 60 minutes in a degree so, 2 degrees 20 minutes = 2.3333 decimal degrees.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you know the longitude of the first tick mark on the top, but not the latitude. Its a bit higher than 54:20N but you don't know how much. The same problem occurs for the latitude markers on the sides.

But if you connect the tick markers you can then get the lat and long of the intersections. Here's how it looks with some horizontal and vertical rulers added using GIMP:

[image]

Now if I add points at those intersections I know their lat-long and I can use the georeferencer as normal. Note this assumes the lines of latitude and longitude are straight and at right angles - which might not be true if this is a something like a conical map projection, but then you'd probably notice that the rectangles of the grid created weren't true rectangles.

Comment: Would I need to convert the Northing and Eastings into Lat/long before georeferencing or could I just input the Northing/Eastings?

Comment: I can only see latitudes and longitudes - the only "conversion" you need to do is convert 54 degrees and 20 minutes into 54.3333 decimal degrees (and do the same for the other) if your georeferencer only accepts decimal degree input.

Comment: Im very new to georeferencing, why would I change 54.20 into 54.3333?

Comment: On your map, the text `54°20'N` means 54 degrees and 20 minutes north of the equator. A minute is 1/60th part of a degree, so 20 minutes is one third of a degree. In decimal, that is 0.3333 recurring. So in decimal degrees that latitude is 53.3333. I don't know if the georeferencing software you plan to use wants you to type degrees and minutes or decimal degrees, but if its decimal degrees you need to enter 53.3333 and not 53.20.

Comment: Ok this makes alot of sense, thankyou. The projection I am using is ED50 31N, which I believe is Meters not decimals. I am also going to georeference on ArcGIS V10.6.1 Which allows me to add xy point data on a map

Comment: The projection you may be using elsewhere is irrelevant at this stage. What the georeferencer does is relate pixel coordinates on the image to real-world coordinates of known points on the image. In this case we have lat-long coordinates (which are probably EPSG:4326 lat-long, or near enough at this scale). Once your GIS knows where the image is in that system then you can reproject it (if necessary, raster reprojection is often not needed) to any other system.

Comment: The important projection is **the one this image was made with**. If it is an image in ED50 31N, which is a UTM system, then lat-long on the image isn't a rectangular grid and the guidelines I've drawn will not align with true lat-long on the ground. But it looks like that is a Mercator or other rectangular projection so that's okay.

Answer (score 1):

After research I have found that OSPAR have a marine protected areas network with downloadable shapefiles.

https://odims.ospar.org/en/submissions/ospar_mpa_2021_07/